# I believe my scraper got blocked, but I can access the website via a regular browser, how can they do this?

Tags: python, web-scraping, ip-address, user-agent

I recently wrote a rather simple scraper using requests and BeautifulSoup. The scraper worked perfectly until one day, I ran it and received a "Connection reset by peer, Error 54". Despite there being multiple questions about getting around Error 54's that is not what I am wondering.

To test whether or not the blocked my specific IP or computer, I ran the code on a different machine and IP address and it worked fine. The troubling thing however, is that even on my old machine, I can access the site on a regular browser perfectly.

I am wondering both how the website was able to do this without blocking my IP outright and if anyone has any tips for avoiding this in the future.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is for specific programming questions not tips for working around networking security measures and/or help committing unauthorized network scans.

Comment: What is the site? Have you read their tos?

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=scraping%20without%20getting%20blocked

Comment: Lots of ways to do this, from user-agent headers to much more involved client fingerprinting and timing analysis. To figure out which method any particular site uses would be sheer guesswork, and to do so without even knowing which site this is (and whether they're behind any security-gateway service a la CloudFlare)... guesswork in the extreme.

Comment: Sorry all for not providing many details. I was asking to get a few pointers. Thanks to those who gave them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering both how the website was able to do this without blocking my IP outright and ...

By examining all manner of things about your request, some straight-forward and some arcane. Straight-forward items include user-agent headers, cookies, correctly spelling of dynamic URLs.

Arcane items include your IP address, the timing of your request, the frequency of related requests, the content of other headers.

> ... if anyone has any tips for avoiding this in the future.

Yes. Contact the owners of the website in question and cooperate with any restrictions they have in place. Examine the terms of your license to use their website (if it is a general public license, it is often called "Terms of Service"). Ensure that you operate exclusively within those terms.

If the website data is available via an API, and your use falls within the API's license terms, use it instead of screen-scraping. The format of the data will be more consistent, your code will run faster, and you will be less of a burden (or threat) to the website owner.

Comment: Thanks Rob for taking the time to answer my question. I know it was rather general, I'm just learning the ropes now though so my understanding of scraping is rather, well, general. I'll accept your answer to give you your points and cause it helps me get started. Thanks again!